# Maximum frequency in any row and column

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, matrices

I have been given 2D matrix with some elements. I want to find out what is maximum frequency in any row and column.
Example:
1 2 1 2
3 4 1 2
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
Maximum frequency is 6 which occurs in last row and last column of matrix.
Constraints
No. of rows X No. of columns <= 10^6
1<=Elements in Matrxi <= 10^6

**My approach**
Firstly, I have calculated frequency of a number in each row and each column
Travel row wise. Let x be element we are searching, a=frequency[x] in this row. Then loop for each column, b=frequency[x] in that column.
ans=max(ans, a+b)
Complexity of above code is O(nm^2) where n is no. of rows and m is no. of columns.
I am looking for better complexity.

Comment: This appears to be copied from the Codechef 2016 February-long challenge, specifically [the Sereja and Two Lines](https://www.codechef.com/FEB16/problems/SEATL) problem (SEATL).  The [CodeChef rules](https://www.codechef.com/FEB16) say that discussing the problem on any online platform is against CodeChef's rules.  1. I mention this so that other folks can be aware; you might want to wait until after Feb 15th to answer, so that this doesn't contribute to cheating in online contests.

Comment: 2. Mike, please credit your sources.  You've copied the matrix directly from CodeChef's page.  Generally speaking, copying without attribution constitutes plagiarism; [that's not welcome here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/160917).  I recommend that you edit the question to credit your sources and acknowledge where the problem came from.

Answer (score 0):

$O(nm \log (m+n))$ should not be difficult. Insert all elements in a rows and columns in height balanced search trees (one each for each row and each column) which also keep the frequencies. Now for each row and column just search the number in corresponding row search tree and column search tree and add the frequencies. Then compute the minimum of this sum.